how to design resource which are dependent on another resource
I have two resources configurations and clusters.
/clusters

/configurations

clusters are created using configuration.
How to design an api, to get the list of clusters created using a configuration id?
can it be implemented as
/configurations/{:config-id}/clusters?

I have dilema here, because clusters are not sub-resource of a configuration.

Neither HTTP nor REST care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers, so long as they are consistent with the general purpose production rules described by RFC 3986 and RFC 9110.
In particular, they don't care about the meaning of the URI.
And that's good: it means that you can use the extra degrees of freedom to choose resource identifiers that make things easier for the humans you care about.
/configurations/{:config-id}/clusters

That's fine.
If you felt a need to have the path start with the clusters prefix, then a boring but acceptable spelling would be
/clusters?configuration={:config-id}

If you needed to have the config-id included in the path, instead of the query_part, then you might consider
/clusters/configuration={:config-id}
/clusters/configuration:{:config-id}
/clusters/configuration;id={:config-id}

You could even do something like
/clusters/{:config-id};configuration

These are also fine, so long as the humans you care about can figure them out, and the logic in your server is smart enough to route the requests to the correct handling logic.
